# ssl with boost and securepages module

Tags: commerce, caching, ssl

I have this doubt. 
I have a website in drupal 7 currently live (Kickstart2) and use as cache management boost 
I have to buy a ssl certificate on my domain and with this certificate I would like to cover only the path checkout/* and user/*

I would like to proceed in this steps:

1. buy ssl certificate for the main domain
2. install the module securepages
3. configure the module with the path checkout / * and user / *

by this configuration I expect something like that:
http://www.example.com/mypage but https://www.example.com/checkout
only /checkout will be in https. Is it right?

This is just as reasoning and how to configure the module? Is it the right way?

Last question: 
I read that boost module does not work well with ssl, that it means that my checkout/* pages will not be under cache, but the rest of the pages? Rest of the path like /about or /news are all done under cache? 
You can confirm this to me?

Ty guys

Comment: As far as I know boost is only for anonymous pages. Use Authcache rather. In its doc pages it explains how to set it up for Commerce. Also install autcache block for your basket (it neglects to mention that). I also had issues with js and css files not loading from hosted servers. I had to rewrite the protocol to these urls manually.

Comment: So with Authcache module I can comfortable using the ssl? You've tried it with ssl? It seem simple to configure.

Comment: I do have a site running over ssl using authcache. However, all of my site runs over ssl, not just selected pages. I don't know how authcache will behave when having to switch between protocols. I don't know your setup but it is quite easy to test on a development machine. You need to install a self-signed certificate.

Comment: I have a site with over 5000 unique users per day, boost work well with good performance, anyway I could change in authcache module without problems. I ask myself how is the performance with many users. Do you have sites over authcach with a lot of traffic? How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

1. Should I use securepages?

**No.** The best practice these days is to just go with https for the whole site.

2. How do I go about caching my https content?

On a normal site, the https wouldn't matter, you can cache static content regardless of how encrypted it travels. BUT. The caching questions are legitimate because it is an eCommerce site and with that (by default), even anonymous users will have a session. Most default caching systems do not work with per-user sessions, unless you use something like authcache.